# XQuery (saxon) failing with a schema (XPath works)

Tags: xquery, saxon

I switched in saxon from XPath to XQuery and on the selects where I have a schema I'm getting the error message:

> A typed input document can only be used with a schema-aware query

My setup is:

```
InputSource xmlSource = new InputSource(xmlData);
SAXSource saxSource = new SAXSource(reader, xmlSource);
Source schemaSource = new StreamSource(schemaFile);
Configuration config = createEnterpriseConfiguration();
config.addSchemaSource(schemaSource);
Processor processor = new Processor(config);
SchemaValidator validator = new SchemaValidatorImpl(processor);

DocumentBuilder doc_builder = processor.newDocumentBuilder();
if(!preserveWhiteSpace)
    doc_builder.setWhitespaceStrippingPolicy(WhitespaceStrippingPolicy.ALL);
doc_builder.setSchemaValidator(validator);
XdmNode root_node = doc_builder.build(saxSource);
XQueryCompiler compiler = processor.newXQueryCompiler();
```

Is there something additional I need to do on queries where there is a schema?

thanks - dave

Answer (score 1):

Call `XQueryCompiler.setSchemaAware(true);`

This isn't the default because it's good for the optimizer to know whether the data is likely to be typed or untyped, and it's inefficient to generate schema-aware code if the data is untyped (conversely, when the data is typed, schema-aware code is typically faster -- though the savings can be eaten up by the extra cost of validating the input).

Comment: I just tried that. Got the same "requires a Saxon-EE license" which I believe is what we purchased.

Comment: Also, I will only call this if we do have a schema. So we should be good on the speed hit.

Comment: The "requires a license" message means the license file isn't being picked up for some reason. Running with the -t option can give you better diagnostics.